# What does the following for loop syntax mean in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

I came across this syntax, not sure what it means.

```
  for( ; ; )
  {
    //do stuff like read from a handle etc.
  }
```

I am still on my learning curve in C so vote down if you want if it's a lame question.

Comment: It's called a "for-ever" loop.

Comment: you are gonna want a `break` or `return` inside that loop, too.

Comment: @LeeMeador - not necessarily.  Looks more to me like a thread function with blocking calls, ie. designed to run forever.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an infinite loop. Same as `while(1)`

Really the only important thing to look at is that for loops look like `for (initialize vars; continue condition; counters)` . Since there's no continue condition it just keeps going (unless there's a break or return statement in there somewhere).

Comment: It's actually a `continue condition`, which is the exact opposite of a `stop condition`.

Comment: @netcoder You're right I always think of it as a when do i stop condition :P

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why it my be preferable to while(1) sometimes?

Comment: @ArunavDev: `while (1)` might generate a warning with [some compilers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t66728h(VS.80).aspx), but `for (;;)` doesn't (AFAIK).